# resolver executes after the component's ngoninit

Tags: angular

I have the below component which i'm trying to setup with a resolver, so the data should populate from the resolver.  whenever i run the application though, no data is there, and using the debugger the ngoninit gets hit before the breakpoints in the resolver.  also there is data, as i'm able to subscribe to the service in the ngonint and get data back, without using the resolver.

my route:

```
    export const appRoutes:Routes = [
    { path: 'application', component: ApplicationListComponent, resolve: {applications: ApplicationListResolver}},
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/application', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

my resolver:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { ApplicationService } from '../../service/application.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApplicationListResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private _applicationService: ApplicationService) { }

  // Resolver automatically subscribes to an observable call that it gets
  resolve() {
    return this._applicationService.getApplications();
  }
}
```

my component:

```
import { IApplication } from './../entities/application.model';
import { ApplicationService } from './../service/application.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'oats-application-list',
  templateUrl: './application-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application-list.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationListComponent implements OnInit {
  applications: IApplication[];

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.applications = this.route.snapshot.data['applications'];
   // this._applicationService.getApplications().subscribe((data:IApplication[]) => {
   //     this.applications = data;
   // });
  }

}
```

my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/RX';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IApplication } from '../entities/application.model';

@Injectable()
export class ApplicationService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getApplications():Observable<IApplication[]>{
    return this.http.get<IApplication[]>('http://localhost/myapp/api/application')
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<IApplication[]>('getApplications', [])));
  }

    // operation is the method that triggered this, result the default value when there is error (optional)
    private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
      // function which takes an error of type any and returns an Observable of type T
      return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.of(result as T);  // return the result cast to type T
      }
    }  
}
```

Shouldn't the resolver get hit first and then component? I get the same result if I remove the path: '' from my routes and hit the localhost:4200/application url directly.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, I was missing the router-outlet.